# Formatar resultado de soma com a virgula - Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, matemática

Estou realizando um somatório de todos os valores referente a uma coluna de uma tabela.

Ao retornar par ao html, está sendo retornado sem a vírgula.

Como posso proceder para que a vírgula seja apresentada na segunda casa ?

```js
var valor_recibo = 0;

$(".valor_recibo").each(function() {
  var num = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
  valor_recibo += num;
});

$('#totalrecibo').html(valor_recibo);
```

O valor é retornado em uma span assim : 25998 
Sendo que a forma correta é assim : 259,98

Código Html

```html
<table class="table table-striped m-table m-table--head-bg-success">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Valor Recibo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="valor_recibo">100</td>
      <td class="valor_recibo">200</td>
      <td class="valor_recibo">300</td>
      <td class="valor_recibo">400</td>
      <td class="valor_recibo">500</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="totalrecibo"> aqui retorna o valor </div>
```

Comment: O valor é retornado em uma span assim : 25998 Sendo que a forma correta é assim : 259,98

Comment: O parseInt converte para inteiro. troque por parseFloat.

Comment: Realizei a troca. mas ele ainda mantem o valor sem a virgula.

Comment: Mas aí tem que ver o que vc está somando. Quais os valores que vc está somando?

Comment: estou somando várias <td class="valor_recibo">.

Comment: você gostaria que eu postasse o código html ?

Comment: Seria interessante.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78753/discussion-between-robson-freitas-and-dvd).

Comment: Imagino que o problema esteja na expressão regular. Tente trocar `/[^0-9]/g` por `/[^0-9,]/g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `parseInt` impedirá de você trabalhar com casas decimais. Em vez disso, use `parseFloat`.

Também seu `replace` está errado. Se na `td` possui apenas números, faça um `replace` substituindo apenas a vírgula. O JavaScript considera casas decimais o que vier à direita do ponto, e não da vírgula.

No final do cálculo, você precisa ainda converter o resultado para string e substituir o ponto pela vírgula:

```js
var valor_recibo = 0;

$(".valor_recibo").each(function() {
  var num = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',', '.'));
  valor_recibo += num;
});

$('#totalrecibo').html(valor_recibo.toString().replace('.', ','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped m-table m-table--head-bg-success">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Valor Recibo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="valor_recibo">224,30</td>
      <td class="valor_recibo">237,60</td>
      <td class="valor_recibo">194,41</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="totalrecibo"> aqui retorna o valor </div>
```

Comment: Problema solucionado. Muito obrigado!!!